# TOSCA: Scan Application - Browser option missing

Tags: tosca

I'm a newbie in TOSCA world. :)

Need help.. I wanted to scan an application by browser, but the 'Browser' option is not displayed. I'm using a trial version (self study purpose), not sure if I'm missing anything or do I need to do some configurations?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Scanning HTML applications in a browser can be triggered by selecting **Scan Application -> Desktop** on a Modules folder.

**Desktop** is used here as an umbrella term for all applications with a GUI. More information can be found in the [Tosca XScan documentation](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.1.0&url=tchb/create_modules_xscan.htm)

Answer (score 0):

While doing the right click for scan options (on a folder in Module Section), do it holding shift key.

.i.e,

"Shift + Right Click" - > it will open the same context menu but additional scanning options would be shown under "Scan Application Option."

Go for **Html** in that list for browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden in plain sight. We faced the same problem when we upgraded to TOSCA 10 from TOSCA 9.2.

In your screenshot, you can see that 'Desktop' option there (Scan Application > Desktop). Once you click that you can scan all that is open and scan-able! Desktop serves for all browser, non-browser.

See here: https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.1.0&url=tchb/create_modules_xscan.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI

From TOSCA Version 10 Scan -> Browser option is not available and you can use scan -> Desktop to scan. In the version 9.3 you will still find this option.